# Activerecord sort by column and then created_at?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

So I have a table of items. Each item has a status that can be "daily", "monthly", "yearly", or "outstanding".

What I'm trying to do is create a single Activerecord (or SQL) query that arranges the outstanding items first (by created_at) and then the rest of the items (regardless of their status) by their created_at date, while limiting the total number of items returned to 15.

So for instance, if I have 30 outstanding items and 30 yearly items, the query returns 15 outstanding items (by their created_at).

If I have 10 outstanding items and 30 yearly items, it returns those 10 outstanding items (by created_at) and then 5 yearly items (by created_at) — the outstanding items returned should be at the beginning of the returned array.

If I do not have any outstanding items and 30 yearly items, it would return 15 yearly items by their created_at date.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Why a single query? 2 queries in worst case scenario will do the trick. Best case triggers 1 query.

Comment: I think this single query is not possible with ORM

Comment: The reason for the single query is that I am implementing an infinite scroll and need to retain the page number offset for requests. Could have used two different offset numbers, but that seemed janky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, just define a scope like this:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :ordered, -> {
    joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN ( SELECT id, created_at, status
                             FROM items
                             WHERE items.status = 'outstanding'
                           ) AS temp ON temp.id = items.id AND temp.status = items.status"
         ).order('temp.created_at NULLS LAST, items.status, items.created_at')
    }
end
```

The magic is: (expect your table name is `items`)

- Left join `items` with `outstanding items`. So `temp.id` and `temp.created_at` will be `NULL` for items which don't have status `outstanding`
- Order by `temp.created_at NULLS LAST` first, so the `items` which don't have status `outstanding` will be ordered last. Then just do order by normally: `items.status`(this makes the same statuses will be closed by each other) and `items.created_at`

You can run the query with scope `ordered` for 15 items only:

```
Item.ordered.limit(15)
```

Comment: even though it might be what OP requests, and return the right result, I would not want to see such code in the applications I work on, since it is not readable + it is achievable through AR ORM. By no means I say it is bad, just a point of view - Ruby is about readability, after all. At the worst there are query objects pattern, and you could put it there, but still..

Comment: @AndreyDeineko: Agree, readability is matter, but for me programming is not a convention, everything needs to be broken to see what is better.  I'm still a learner, not a professional developer, I think :). I got your idea, thanks!

Comment: professionalism is a subjective thing, but having own experience is something definitely valuable. And hey, it is your answer that being accepted, so.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Though it's not a single query in worst case scenario (2 queries), but it solves your problem:

```
items = Item.where(:status => "outstanding").order('created_at DESC').limit(15)
items = (items.size == 15) ? items : items + Item.where('status != ?', "outstanding").order('created_at DESC').limit(15-items.size)
```

Comment: I think he wants that. As per the question "`query that arranges the outstanding items first (by created_at) and then the rest of the items (regardless of their status) by their created_at date`"

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about single query, but here is an adequate solution:

```
scope :ordered,     -> { order(:created_at) }
scope :outstanding, -> { where(status: :outstanding).ordered }

def self.collection
  return ordered.limit(15) if outstanding.count.zero?
  return outstanding.limit(15) if outstanding.count >= 15
  outstanding + ordered.limit(15 - outstanding.count)
end

Item.collection # will return the array of your records
```